# PHP add content to a JSON file with the correct structure (Lazy Loader)

Tags: php, html, json

I am trying to create a JSON file with the correct format to be used by Lazy Loader through PHP. I'm putting the contents in an associative array and putting it inside another multi-dimensional array.

Here is the code I am using for this:

```
<?php

//I will fetch this content from the database later. This is just for example.
$posts = array("<div>Item 1</div>", "<div>Item 2</div>", "<div>Item 3</div>");

$items = array();
$length = count($posts);

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    $items["html"] = $posts[$i];
}

$posts_datas = array("items" => array($items));

/* JSON file */
file_put_contents('lazyloader/datas.json', json_encode($posts_datas, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

?>
```

The file is created and has the correct format for only one element. I need them all.

JSON file code:

```
{
    "items": [
        {"html": "<div>Item 3<\/div>"}
    ]
}
```

Code I want:

```
{
     "items": [
         {"html": "<div>Item 1<\/div>"},
         {"html": "<div>Item 2<\/div>"},          
         {"html": "<div>Item 3<\/div>"}
     ]
}
```

I need your help. Does anyone have a solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: The json file you want is not valid JSON

Comment: Also `{}` denotes an object. Do you actually want each `items` to be an object or an array

Comment: ALSO You cannot have more than one assoc key with the same name in the same array

Comment: @RiggsFolly But this is the JSON code provided by Lazy Loader. Yes, to be an object because it is the structure requested. I can not use array to get the result. Do you know any other way to get this result?

Comment: The current content of the file is valid, but what you want to do to it is not

Comment: @RiggsFolly So it is not possible to create the JSON file with this structure through PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok amended once I understood the question better.

Assuming `$posts` is collected from your database via a query this would achieve what you want.

```
//I will fetch this content from the database later. This is just for example.
$posts = array("<div>Item 1</div>", "<div>Item 2</div>", "<div>Item 3</div>");

$items = array();

foreach ( $posts as $post){
    $items['items'][] = ['html' => $post];
}   

// now rewrite the file with the new content added
file_put_contents('datas.json', json_encode($items, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

The result would be

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "html": "<div>Item 1<\/div>"
        },
        {
            "html": "<div>Item 2<\/div>"
        },
        {
            "html": "<div>Item 3<\/div>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I only have one question: Does this work if I fetch the posts dynamically from the database? For example, if post number 2 is deleted will it also disappear from the json file?

Comment: Ah one moment. So you want the JSON to present the current state read from the database. I though you wanted to add something to an existing json file

Comment: So does the `datas.json` file get created from new in this script? Or are you adding things to an already existing `datas.json` file?

Comment: The posts are read through the database. Each time the page is loaded the script is executed and the JSON file with the posts is created / updated.